# Safari on iOS 14 breaks date/time inputs when used with template tags or custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, web-component, ios14

When using a webComponent with Safari on iOS 14 (iOS 13 is working fine) the date inputs are rendered as date inputs but behaviors as a text input. All other browsers and devices work as expected.

Is there a an issue with the code or is there a better/different way this should be done that is working for iOS 14? When reading the contents as HTML string (innerHTML) the inputs work as expected.

HTML:

```html
<h1>Without template tag</h1>
<input type="date" />
<input type="time" />
<input type="datetime-local" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="text" />


<h1>With template tag</h1>
<div id="type-tester"></div>

<template id="test1">
<div>
    <input type="date" />
    <input type="time" />
    <input type="datetime-local" />
    <input type="number" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
</template>
<template id="test2">
<div>
    <input type="date" />
    <input type="time" />
    <input type="datetime-local" />
    <input type="number" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
</template>

<my-test></my-test>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
var template = document.getElementById('test1');
var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

// Workaround
//var div = document.createElement('div');
//div.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
//clone = div.firstElementChild;

var inputDate = clone.querySelector('input[type=date]');
var inputTime = clone.querySelector('input[type=time]');
var inputDatetime = clone.querySelector('input[type=datetime-local]');
var inputNumber = clone.querySelector('input[type=number]');
var inputText = clone.querySelector('input[type=text]');

document.body.appendChild(clone);

var tester = document.getElementById('type-tester');
tester.textContent = 'Types; date=' + inputDate.type + ', time=' + inputTime.type + ', datetime=' + inputDatetime.type + ', number=' + inputNumber.type + ', text=' + inputText.type + ' (' + navigator.userAgent + ')';

customElements.define('my-test',
    class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            var template = document.getElementById('test2');
            var templateContent = template.content;

            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(
                templateContent.cloneNode(true)
            );
        }
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle: template tag with cloneNode](https://jsfiddle.net/g5xp3u76/1/)

[JSFiddle: template tag with customElements/webComponent](https://jsfiddle.net/znkpLuce/)

## Progress

There is a bugreport on [webkit.org](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216985) with the status: RESOLVED FIXED

Fixed iOS version: 17.0.3 (WebKit 605.1.15)

It was not working for the iOS 15.* versions and I didn't test the iOS 16.* versions. With the latest version (17.0.3) it does work.

Comment: I can't test SF. My recommendation is to make it an issue at: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues All (Apple, Google.Mozilla etc.) engineers are monitoring that issue list. And make a JSFiddlle, CodePen, whatever, so they can test with one click.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks for your response, it is not only a problem with webComponents but also with cloneNode on a template tag. The code showed both implementations. I added 2 different JSFiddle links for both cases.

Comment: FWIW I've seen similar behavior in our app that uses a WKWebView. We use knockout as a framework and if we use that to set the `type` attribute then it does show a date picker, but it's a different one to Safari's, and if I hit reset on it after selecting a date it's crashing our entire app. Had zero issues on iOS 13 and below.